# Where are the simple AWK examples to get started?

Tags: awk

All of my codes fail. They should print "he", "hello" and "5 \n 3", respectively:

```
awk -v e='he' {print $e}       // not working, why?
awk NF { print hello }
awk { print ARGV[5,3] }
```

**Are there some simple examples about AWK?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first, you don't use $ for variables inside awk, try this instead:

```
fury> echo | awk -v e='he' '{print e}'
he
```

For the second, your condition NF means NF!=0 so it will only print for non empty lines:

```
fury> echo | awk 'NF {print "hello"}'
fury> echo "7 8" | awk 'NF {print "hello"}'
hello
```

I've never seen your syntax for the third one, ARGV is a single dimensional array, so you can use:

```
fury> awk 'BEGIN {print ARGV[5]}' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5
fury> awk 'BEGIN {print ARGV[5] "\n" ARGV[3]}' 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
5
3
```

Note I'm using a BEGIN block for the third, otherwise it'll try to open and process 1, 2, 3, ... as files.

Comment: What about with different arrays? Can I divide the elements of different arrays by one another, like:

1     DIVIDE        2
2     DIVIDE        4   

=>    0,5
      0,5

Possible?

Answer (score 4):

First, basic shell scripting sanity:

- Always enclose your script in single quotes

Note that the script is a single argument - or a filename with '`-f file`'.

An awk script is a sequence of '`<pattern> <action>`' pairs.  The action is enclosed in braces '`{}`' for clarity - and sanity, again.

As Pax said, the first example should be:

```
awk -v -e e='he' '{ print e }'
```

The second example is inscrutable - you probably meant:

```
awk '{ print "hello" }'
```

The variable NF is the number of fields on the line.  You might get awk to interpret

```
awk 'NF { print "hello" }'
```

as if there is any data on the input line (NF != 0, or number of fields is not zero), then print 'hello'.

The last example is likewise inscrutable; ARGV is an array of the arguments to 'awk', and the command line provided none.  But it is a one-dimensional array.  Your sub-scripting notation wants to treat it like a Python dictionary or Perl hash, with two indexes combined.  You're OK - awk supports associative arrays; but since you didn't add anything to the array at ARGV[5,2], it won't print anything.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "hello" | awk ' {print $0} '
echo "hello" | awk ' {print $1} '
```

Note that $0 returns the whole record, and $1 just the first entry; awk starts its counters at 1.  So

```
echo "hello1 hello2 hello3" | awk ' {print $0} '
```

returns  hello1 hello2 hello3.  While

```
echo "hello1 hello2 hello3" | awk ' {print $3} '
```

will return hello3

I like this [awk tutorial.](http://sparky.rice.edu/~hartigan/awk.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use this [site.](http://people.cs.uu.nl/piet/docs/nawk/nawk_toc.html) The O'Reilly [Sed & Awk](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565922255) book is good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Also, lots of useful info and tutorials at http://awk.info